# SQL Server LIKE containing bracket characters(Variable)

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

How can I search in a letter in variable like this

```
Where Name Like '%@Variable%'
```

Comment: `where name like '%%`, or for unicode `where name like N'%%` ?

Comment: Something not adding up here. Is that a table variable? Else, wouldn't you want to do `Where @Variable Like '%%'`?

Comment: Is the arrow even part of the question, or are you just directing us to the next line visually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @ahmad_lababidi welcome to stackoverflow,

If it is not an ASCII character and generally requires a column of type NVARCHAR and a literal with string N '' (Except when the encoding accepts symbols)

for example, the UNICODE code of your character is 55357, so you can search for this character in your query, as in the following example.

```
CREATE TABLE #FIND (NAME nvarchar(10));
INSERT INTO #FIND VALUES (N'');

SELECT UNICODE(N'')   --> 55357

SELECT *
FROM #FIND
WHERE NAME LIKE '%' + NCHAR(55357) + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `nvarchar` instead, and make sure you prefix your literal string with an `N` to denote that the literal string is an `nvarchar`:

```
DECLARE @variable varchar(1) = N'';

SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourColumn LIKE N'%' + @variable + N'%';
```